# AI for time table generator software

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to develop a time table generator software for my college. Obviously it requires a great deal of constraint satisfaction i.e. I need to satisfy a lot of rules in order to generate a bunch of time tables where classes do not clash. After doing some research and reading [this article](http://www.ijcse.com/docs/IJCSE11-02-03-027.pdf), I feel I need to use some AI in it. Now, I am a complete newbie to AI. Can anyone tell me which algorithm will work best in my case?

Comment: I frankly don't think that was such a broad question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest algorithm that you can use for this problem is genetic algorithm (or any other evolutionary algorithm). Solving this problem using GA is very simple but yet effective. There are lots of papers and codes that have used this approach for this problem.

If you have few rules and constraints, you may want to use exact straightforward techniques like backtracking with CSP heuristics to speed it up, but if there are lots of classes and constraints, I suggest Genetic Algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please expand it a little... probably with an example.

Comment: Sure
you should take a look at the algorithm itself first. It is very simple and you can learn it in a little time.
This algorithm tries to generate all possible solutions and evaluate their fitness.
Considering that you have learned how to use GA, this is what you should do for timetabling:
1. Create your chromosomes (here each chromosome is a possible solution)
2. Train GA
3. use chromosomes with best fitnesses in the last generation
You can search using keywords like solving university timetabling using genetics algoithm. There are lots of examples and papers about this on web
Good Luck :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer really made me optimistic about the project! :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, not a trivial task indeed. Problems like this one are VERY hard to solve.

Here I can recommend you two things:

1. Use an existing CSP/COP solver and describe your constraints in its language. These solvers are very good, fast and tuned, being developed for years.
2. Educate yourself in the area of Discrete Optimization (there was a course at coursera.org with the same name which was great). Only after you grasp the basics of how these things work can you try to write your own solver. But let you be warned! Discrete optimization is pain and suffering :-).

This is by no means a suitable place to just tell you how CSP/COP works. It is a very broad and difficult field.

I wish you good luck!

Comment: Thanks! So, don't you agree that the Genetic Algorithm thing would not be very difficult, as suggested by MSH?

Comment: No, I definitely agree! I'm doing my PhD around evolutionary algorithms and the basic concept is very easy to grasp. But from my experience using plain genetic algorithm in its simplest form is often not good enough. And if your problem is not a black box, using specialized solver is better most of the time.